# Hide totals in the order history table and view order popup based on order status in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I am using an order proposal plugin which creates a custom gateway for users on the checkout page, so that when they checkout, their order gets created with the status "Proposal Requested".

At present, i've set my site up so that prices are hidden in the front end (in most places such as, product loop, single shop page, cart, mini-cart, checkout etc) since the flow of the site is

1. A customer adds their desired items to the cart.
2. They request a quote on the checkout page and their order gets created with the Order Status set to "Proposal Requested". At present, customers see this order in their Order History table and the total is shown for their order.
3. Shop managers get the notification and change the status of the order from "Proposal Requested" to "Proposal" after filling in the prices of the products requested etc.
4. Customer receives notification that the Proposal has been sent and they can accept or decline the proposal. **At this point, when the order status is set to "Proposal" customers should then finally be able to see the total show up in the "Total" column of their Order History table, for that particular order.**

So basically, what I'm trying to do is, if the order status for a particular order is set to "proposal_requested", then the cell in the Total column for that order should show something applicable like "-" or "N/A", as customers aren't allowed to see the prices before a quote is sent to them. If it is possible, the prices from the "View Order" popup for this order status should also be hidden.

Here's what I have tried so far which works, to remove the price column from the table in the Order View popup.

- Copied the order-details-item.php file from `woocommerce/templates/order/` to my child theme: `my-child-theme/woocommerce/order/`
- Look for the following line
  `<?php echo $order->get_formatted_line_subtotal( $item ); ?>` and replace it (as well as the `<td>` tags wrapping around it) with the following:

```
        $order_data     = $order->get_data();
        $order_status   = $order_data['status'];

        if( $order_status == 'order-proposalreq' ) {              
            echo '<td class="woocommerce-table__product-total product-total"> - </td>'; // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped 
        }
        else{
            echo '<td class="woocommerce-table__product-total product-total">' . $order->get_formatted_line_subtotal( $item ) . '</td>'; // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped 
        }
```

This basically inputs "-" in the price cell for orders that are in the "order-proposalreq" status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen in the template files, both totals use the `get_formatted_order_total()` function.

So to adjust the display of the totals, based on the order status we can use the `woocommerce_get_formatted_order_total` filter hook.

**Note:** adjust the "has order status" to your needs:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_get_formatted_order_total( $formatted_total, $order, $tax_display, $display_refunded ) {
    // For a certain order status
    if ( $order->has_status( 'completed' ) ) {
        return __( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' );
    }
    
    // Show the original
    return $formatted_total;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_formatted_order_total', 'filter_woocommerce_get_formatted_order_total', 10, 4 );
```

**Result:**

[image]

As you can see, this works in both cases, **only there is an additional text** 'for ... items' **in the order history table**.

---

**To avoid this** we can overwrite the existing column, via the `woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_{$column_id}` hook.

```php
// Overwrite the existing 'order-total' column
function filter_woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_order_total( $order ) { 
    // For a certain order status
    if ( $order->has_status( 'completed' ) ) {
        echo __( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' );
    // Show the original
    } else {
        // Get item count
        $item_count = $order->get_item_count() - $order->get_item_count_refunded();
        
        // translators: 1: formatted order total 2: total order items
        echo wp_kses_post( sprintf( _n( '%1$s for %2$s item', '%1$s for %2$s items', $item_count, 'woocommerce' ), $order->get_formatted_order_total(), $item_count ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_order-total', 'filter_woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_order_total', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide these snippets! They work as intended (: